# #:when keyword information

Tags: scheme, racket

Where can I find documentation regarding `#:when` construction in DrRacket?

Here is full example:

```
(define (problem_9 sum)
  (for*/first ([c (in-range 3 (- sum 2))]
               [b (in-range 2 c)]
               [a (in-range 1 b)]
               #:when (and (= (+ a b c) sum)
                           (= (+ (* a a) (* b b)) (* c c))))
    (+ a b c)))
```

I understand the purpose of it, but want to find documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of `#:when` in a `for`-like expression is explained in the [Reference documentation for `for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html). If you search the Racket docs for `for*/first` and click on the result, you'll see it's documented as taking a sequence of *for-clauses*. The variants of *for-clause* are described in the docs for `for`, at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at the Racket Guide, in the section called "Iteration and Comprehensions": it has a lot of examples of for loops in action:

[More examples of for loops](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for_and_for_%29)